# Xamarin find child fast with point

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like the search for a child on a grid to be super fast. The code I've created now is probably not the fastest way. I've tried implementing the 'GetChildElements()' but it doesn't return any of the children where my code does. Any suggestions on how to make this lighting fast?

touches contains any relatve touched Point(s) within the grid.

```
    private void GetChildWithFrequency(object sender, Point[] touches)
    {
        Layout<View> grid = (Layout<View>)sender;

        foreach (Key child in grid.Children)
        {
            if (touches[0].X >= child.X &&
                touches[0].X <= child.X + child.Width &&
                touches[0].Y >= child.Y &&
                touches[0].Y <= child.Y + child.Height)
            {
                child.LastX = touches[0].X;

                if (LastChild != null)
                {
                    LastChild.Selected = false;
                }

                LastChild = child;

                child.Selected = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many children does the grid have?  Have you done any profiling to determine where any bottlenecks might be?  Can you pre-calculate the bounds of the children in a separate data structure?

Comment: It has 6 * 5 = 30 children but the amount is not the point. This application needs instantaneous reaction from the app because music and an artist using are involved. So any latency I can prevent are valuable.

Comment: can't you just do some basic geometry calcs to figure out the row/col without iterating through the children?

Comment: I'm currently using MR.Gestures to receive touches. It is fast but there is just a bit too much latency between the touch and the actual tone that is produced. So I'm trying to improve code anywhere possible.

Comment: I thought of that but don't have the knowledge on how to do that.

Comment: Each child has a X, Y, Width and Height. It would be possible the do some geometry calculations on that but how would I go about that?

Comment: Ah, right. I know the X, Y from the touch so I can calculate which row and column would be involved. Hmmm... have to think about that. Good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a regular grid of cells and each row is R high and each column is C wide, then a touch at X,Y

```
Row = Y / R;
Col = X / C;
```

for instance, if R = 50 and C = 50, then a touch at (120,410) would be

```
Row = 410 / 50 ==> 8
Col = 120 / 50 ==> 2
```

if you Grid does not start at 0,0 you will need to adjust for that

Comment: Yeah, cool. That what I thought in my last comment above. Thanks Jason. B.t.w. I just saw a video with a 'Joson' at Evolve '16. Is that you?

Comment: that is most likely Jason Smith, who was the original programmer for XF

Comment: Ok, not you :-) sorry, I've been a Xamarin adept on and off. I've written several Xamarin Apps and have not always been happy with the platform. But it seems to have evolved to be pretty mature at the moment. Thanks for the insight.